# String.valueOf(null) & String.valueOf(s)

Tags: java

This is not working (Throwing Nullpointer Exception)

```
String s =  null; 
System.out.println(s); 
System.out.println(String.valueOf(null));
```

But this is

```
String s =  null; 
System.out.println(s); 
System.out.println(String.valueOf(s));
```

why ?? unable to getting. I want understand logic behind.

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: s is variable its type is String, null is a constant it does not have a type.

Answer (score 5):

`String.valueOf(null)` calls `valueOf(char data[])` which in turn calls `new String(data)` which accesses `value.length` -> NPE.

`String.valueOf(someString)` calls `valueOf(Object obj)` which does `return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();`

---

General note: please use a proper IDE. This was not my "knowledge" writing this question but just me using my IDE for ~1 minute to see which methods will actually be called, I did not even *run* the code.